# Document Viewer in ASP.Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm developing a tool in ASP.Net MVC 3 Razor.  There is a page where the candidate uploads the Curriculum Vitae (rtf, pdf, doc, docx formats supported).

I've done that part.  But now the challenging part for me is that, I need to have another page to view the CV uploaded by the Candidate.  So, this is kinda document viewer shown in a browser to see what has been uploaded.  This should work even in the absence of Acrobat / MS word installations.

Please can someone throw some light on this?

Comment: Is your goal to simply return the document itself to the browser?  Or (as your comment about "the absence of Acrobat..." implies) to somehow universally _render_ the document _server-side_ as HTML and return _that_ to the browser?  The former is trivial, the latter will be increasingly difficult based on the number of formats to be supported and the complexity of the documents saved.

Comment: David, Thanks for the comment.  If i understand it right, i look for the first option.  I will just need to show the document (exactly the way candidate uploaded) in a document viewer which is to be shown in a browser.

Comment: Then I have to ask... what's the purpose of the "document viewer"?  If you're returning the raw document then there's no guarantee that the browser will be able to natively view it.  If the viewer is, for example, an `iframe` containing the document then it might break the UX if their browser can't view it.  I suppose you could look for some kind of client-side plugin to view it, such as a Flash plugin or something, but that seems like a deep rabbit hole.  I'd recommend just having a "Download document" button/link/etc. that just returns the document itself.

Comment: Ok. The purpose is this. It's going to be a public facing Internet application. In which case, from any computer, the authorized personnel should be able to see the CV. When I say from any computer, the softwares required (acrobat, word etc) cannot be made mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of commercial and non-commercial solutions for viewing documents on web. Also there are mostly two different types: Flash-based or HTML-based. Also some viewers are cable of viewing remote files and some don't which you need to upload documents to their servers to be able to use their viewers!

If you need quick and free ways I really recommend following options:

- Google Docs document viewer
- http://crocodoc.com/ (Also Commercial)
- https://viewer.zoho.com/home.do (RIP! Not available anymore!)

If you need to secure documents and limit access to authorized users only, then I really recommend going to commercial solutions which will give you more sophisticated APIs to implement it. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: +1 for google docs I've seen this done before for mvc apps

Comment: Great! Thanks for this. Let me try that out...

Comment: zohoviewer is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You may give Doconut a try. More details at http://www.doconut.com
It is able to view all popular document formats and works for MVC also.

PS: I am the author of the tool

Answer (score 1):

At work, we use [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) to convert different document types to XPS and render them in the browser using the [Silverlight Document Toolkit](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/documenttoolkit). Aspose has components for other types of files as well such as PDF and Excel documents. Both products are commercial and especially the Aspose components are not cheap. The combination has worked great for us so far.

Comment: Morten, Thanks for the comment.  Yes, I have exposure to document processing tools like Aspose, Tx Text control etc.  I agree that its extremely useful and advanced.  But here I'm looking for some free tools.  Let me try with what "Qorbani" suggests.  Thanks again...